# How to hide button with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Because of my initial Javascript narrow experience level, I can quite get hang of event flow. This was written in hurry, further edit possible.

I am creating cards(bootstrap cards) stack, just simply cards, and load-button. To avoid any dependency, I am going for Javascript.

I could not understand the event flow or I can not get the load-button hide.

```js
window.onload = testCards;

function testCards() {
  var col_num = document.querySelector(".col-6");
  if (col_num < 10) {
    var loadBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".d-grid .gap-4");
    loadBtn.querySelector(".btn").classList.add("invisible");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h3>Footer card</h3>
<div class "row footer-card">
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>
```

How to hide the "load-more" button when cards number is less than 10.

Comment: Use `loadBtn.querySelector(".btn").style.display='none';` to hide and later if you want to show then do `loadBtn.querySelector(".btn").style.display='block';`

Comment: Start with `col_num`. It is a single element not a number so your `if()` won't be true

Comment: I have corrected and tested my answer. please try it out. @BrownPaul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The were 2 issues with the code. First was with getting the count of the `.card` divs and the second was with the query selector for the button. Try the following where first all the elements with `card` classes are taken and then based on their length we hide the load button.

```js
window.onload = testCards;
function testCards() {
    var col_num =  document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    if(col_num.length < 10) {
        document.querySelector(".btn").style.display='none';
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>Footer card</h3>
    <div class"row footer-card">
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    <div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-grid gap-4">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: What you mean by 3 stacks? 3  more buttons like load?

Answer (score 0):

I commented out what I thought needed to be changed

```js
// window.onload = testCards; It's better to use addEventListener

addEventListener('load', testCards);

function testCards() {
  // const col_num = document.querySelector(".col-6"); his returns an element, comparing it with a number is not valid
  // But what I think you mean is to find out how many .col-6 cards are out there...
  // If that's the case you use querySelectorAll and length
  const col_num = document.querySelectorAll(".col-6").length;
  const loadBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".d-grid.gap-4").querySelector(".btn");
  
  if (col_num > 10) { // changed that to > so if there are more than 10 cards, hide the button
    // When selecting classes of the same element, you select them just like you would in CSS with a period(.) and without spacing
    loadBtn.classList.add("invisible");
  } else {
    loadBtn.classList.remove('invisible');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h3>Footer card</h3>
<div class "row footer-card">
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 card">
    <p>This is card</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the flow is not getting in the if condition because you are not getting length properly.
try this this will work for sure.

```
window.onload = testCards;
function testCards(){
var col_num =  document.querySelectorAll(".col-6");

if(col_num.length < 10){
var loadBtn = document.querySelector(".d-grid");
        loadBtn.querySelector(".btn").style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

Comment: I have checked and fixed the problem. all you need to do is just copy paste the code snippet. @BrownPaul

Comment: I have made changes to the code. here is the fiddle you shared. i have saved changes there. please check it before downgrading answer. 
https://jsfiddle.net/3167zkse/
@BrownPaul

Comment: ... deleted comment,